# why CMD window get the parameter name and not the value of parameter

Tags: windows, vbscript, cmd

I need to run the following command on CMD window under C:\Program Files\CONNECTION

```
 connect  "user_vip"
```

so write short VB script that perform this action

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
USERC = """user_vip"""
Wscript.Echo USERC
oShell.run "cmd /k CD C:\Program Files\CONNECTION & connect USERC   " ,1 , true
```

After I run the VB script I see the following from CMD window

```
connect USERC
```

and not as I expected to see:

```
 connect  "user_vip"
```

why **USERC** parameter in **oShell.run** not get the real value - **"user_vip"** ??

- remark - Wscript.Echo USERC actually print the value - "user_vip" as I expected

Comment: pretty sure you need to quote the path as it contains spaces

Comment: how:  as - connect "USERC" - this cause error ( expected End of statment ) ?

Comment: I tries allot of combination as USERC = """""user_vip""""" or USERC = """ user_vip """ etc ... or "USERC" .. not works also -:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBScript does not interpolate variable content into string literals and a path containing blanks/spaces in a shell command needs quotes (" escaped as "") so change

```
oShell.run "cmd /k CD C:\Program Files\CONNECTION & connect USERC   " ,1 , true
```

to

```
oShell.run "cmd /k CD ""C:\Program Files\CONNECTION"" & connect " & USERC, 1, True
```

**Update wrt comment:**

```
>> userc = "abc"
>> WScript.Echo "cmd /k CD ""C:\Program Files\CONNECTION"" & connect " & USERC
>>
cmd /k CD "C:\Program Files\CONNECTION" & connect abc
```

Comment: Not work _ because char " after the word connect  ( I get expected end of statment )